# Unable to connect to Oracle database using R

Tags: r, oracle, rjdbc

I am unable to make a connection to Oracle Database using R Studio.

Below are the codes that I have executed to set up the connection.

```
library(RJDBC)

1. jdbcDriver =JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",classPath="C:/Users/abc/Downloads/ojdbc6.jar")
```

Above code was successfully executed.

I get an error in the below code.

```
jdbcConnection =dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:data:@//20.666.1.66:1521/lifedata", 
                          user="abc", password="def")
```

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
>     java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified

My R version is 3.4.0

Comment: try `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//20.666.1.66:1521:lifedata`

Comment: I tried this as well. But doesn't work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@20.666.1.66:1521:lifedata` i forget to remove the // try this one

Comment: Tried this as well. Still the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and to get it working I had the following:

```
jdbcDriver =JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",classPath="C:/Users/abc/Downloads/ojdbc6.jar")

jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, 
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//20.666.1.66:1521/lifedata","abc","def")
```